# find overlap spans bewteen two strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given two string `s1` and `s2`, I want to extract all overlap spans `spans` where `len(spans)>=K`

For example:

```
s1 = "Today is Friday. Nice weather, isn't it?"
s2 = "It's Black Friday today. "
K = 1
```

the expected answer is

```
spans = ["Friday"]   # Sensitive to big capital letter
```

here is my implement:

```
def norm(s):
    punctuation = [",", ".", "?", "!"]
    s = s.split()
    for i, x in enumerate(s):
        if any([x.endswith(p) for p in punctuation]):
            s[i] = x[:-1] + " " + x[-1]
    s = " ".join(s)
    s = s.split()
    return s


def func(s1,s2,K=1):
    punctuation = [",", ".", "?", "!"]
    s1 = norm(s1)
    s2 = norm(s2)
    spans = []
    for i, x in enumerate(s1):
        for j in range(K, len(s1)-K):
            cur_span = " ".join(s1[i:i+j])
            if cur_span in " ".join(s2):
                spans.append(cur_span)
    spans = [x for x in spans if x not in punctuation]
    return spans


s1 = "Today is Friday. Nice weather, isn't it?"
s2 = "It's Black Friday today. "
func(s1,s2,1)  # return ['Friday']
```

Seeking for better implement for this function

Comment: Why wouldn't the answer be `" Friday"` instead of just `"Friday"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set.intersection` along with `split`

```
s1_set = set([i.strip('.,?!') for i in s1.split()])
s2_set = set([i.strip('.,?!') for i in s2.split()])

print(s1_set.intersection(s2_set))
# {'Friday'}
```